# How to exit program from a thread in C?

Tags: c

How can a program be stopped from a non-main thread?

I'm creating a new thread.

```
/* Listen for user commands in new thread */
pthread_t tid;
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &commands, NULL);
```

I want to stop the program if the user types `exit`.

```
/* Listen for user input */
void *commands(void *arg)
{
    char command[100]; 
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Type 'exit' to stop program\n");
        fgets (command, 100, stdin); 
        if(strcmp(command, "exit") == 0) {
            // TODO exit
        }
    }
}
```

I tried calling `exit(0)` from the `commands` method but this did nothing.

Comment: `exit(0)` should indeed do something, namely exit the whole process killing all threads. If you just want to exit the thread, just *return* from the function.

Comment: Ideally you should always end the program gracefully. That means signalling all threads that they should stop, then wait for them to do so. Otherwise you leak resources and might end up with a "ghost process". If any thread should be able to call `exit`, you could implement an `atexit` callback from the main thread who created all others. But ideally only that thread should make the call to close the process.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hm, if exit(0) should do the job then there's probably something else wrong with my program cause the program definitely did not stop. I'll check it out later.

Comment: You might want to put a `printf` where the `// TODO` comment is, just to make sure that the `if` worked as expected. I don't think it did. See [Remove the newline that `fgets` puts in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/3386109).

Comment: Yep feeling like a noob now :D  The `if` block gets never accessed. It should be `strcmp(command, "exit\n")` and not `strcmp(command, "exit")`. I was sure that I've checked that out before asking the question, but it seems like I have not....

Comment: 'Ideally you should always end the program gracefully. That means signalling all threads that they should stop, then wait for them to do so. Otherwise you leak resources and might end up with a "ghost process"' premature stoptimization:(

Answer (score 1):

You should call `pthread_exit` to exit your thread correctly. Note that your application should wait for it to exit using `pthread_join`.

Comment: Does calling `exit` not stop all threads started by the program?

Comment: Yes, and no, join() should be avoided if at all possible and, if unavoidable, take out accident/collision waiver and roadside assistance.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: Exiting the program from a new thread is possible via `exit()` function. In my code sample the `if` block which contains the `exit()` function was never accessed. The following code works fine:

```
/* Listen for user input */
void *commands(void *arg)
{
    char command[100]; 
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Type 'exit' to stop program\n");
        fgets (command, 100, stdin); 
        if(strcmp(command, "exit\n") == 0) {
            exit(0)
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure if just calling `exit()` stops other threads correctly.